# How to resolve Undefined index error in PHP

Tags: php, session-state

I would like to show or hide a given set of links in the navigation bar of a web application based on the login state of the user.

Below is a snippet of my code;

```
<nav>
    <a id="mainpage">Main Page</a>
    <?php if ($_SESSION['logged_in'] === false) { ?>
    <a href="login2.php">Login</a>
    <a href="register.php">Register</a>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <a href="post.php">Posting</a>
    <a href="#">Members posts</a>
    <a href="logout.php" class="outbutton">Logout</a>
    <?php } ?>
</nav>
```

Here, my login page script;

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $username = ($_POST['username']);
    $password = ($_POST['password']);
    $q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND pass='$password'";
    $x = $conn->query($q);

    if ($x->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $x->fetch_assoc()) {
        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
        header("location: welcome.php");
    }
} else {
    die("Username or Password is incorrect");
}
```

My login script works as expected but in the `index.php` page, I get the error below when the user is not logged in:

> Notice: Undefined index: logged_in

On the other hand, the links get displayed in the navigation bar when a user logs in successfully.

I am using `session_start()` at the beginning of my PHP script before any other codes.

Comment: use `isset` function like `if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in']))`

Comment: You need to wrap this line in isset function like this `<?php if ($_SESSION['logged_in'] === false && isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) { ?>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Comment: If you are getting the error even after the login in index page then use session_start() in index page and also isset to check the logged_in session variable.

Comment: @VikashDhiman I only get the error when I'm not logged in and I used session start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below where you are displaying the menu

```
<nav>
<a id="mainpage">Main Page</a>
<?php if (!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) { ?>
    <a href="login2.php">Login</a>
    <a href="register.php">Register</a>
<?php } else { ?>
    <a href="post.php">Posting</a>
    <a href="#">Members posts</a>
    <a href="logout.php" class="outbutton">Logout</a>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should used `isset` function like

```
if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
  // your code
}
```

Detail: first time session is not set & user is logout and there is no `logged_in` index in `$_SESSION` that's why `php` through `warning`

also you can use `@` [for more details](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)

> PHP supports one error control operator: the at sign (@). When
>   prepended to an expression in PHP, any error messages that might be
>   generated by that expression will be ignored.

Comment: If I do this the error will be gone but after logging out the navbar doesn't change it just shows the link for logged in users

Comment: use else condition and add code into else condition

Comment: Is it possible to use @ also on my login page? because I get an error when the user wants to login although there is no problem. here for example  if ($_SESSION['logged_in'] === true) { 

                ?>
                <a href="logout.php" class="outbutton">logout</a>

                <?php
            }
            ?>

Comment: you can use `@` for undefined error but this is not a good way

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start()
if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
    echo "SHOW MY LOGGED IN SESSION ".$_SESSION['logged_in'];
}else
```